# Default card assignment to self

Tags: trello, user-interface, trello-cards, trello-boards

I'm just getting acquainted with Trello and I do not have much experience with other tools. I am looking for a tool that can help me manage several personal projects and I've started out by setting up several boards for them and populating them with cards, some complising multiple steps. I think I'm on the right track in terms of understanding how you intend someone to use this tool, except in my case the number of users = 1.

Is there some way to make the board's owner the default member of all the component cards? Since I'm using this tool primarily for my own personal projects, all of the cards need to be assigned to me and I want to be able to see cards from the different boards show up in the "Cards" space. Maybe I'm missing something? Manually assigning each card to myself seems like the kind of repetitive task that I should be able to avoid.

Comment: A fast way to assign your self to a card: make the card active (by holding the mouse pointer over it, you don't need to open it) and press [space].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately not, there's currently no way to specify default values (such as auto-adding a member) to cards.
You can check the [Trello dev board](http://trello.com/dev) and maybe make a feature request.

Answer (score 14):

It may not be automatic to assign yourself when creating new cards, but this instruction from Trello is about as it gets without being automatic.

From Trello:

> To assign yourself to a card, press the space key while hovering over the card or when the card is open.

Answer (score 3):

The Butler Power-up Plugin can easily do this for you

[image]

Comment: This should selected as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Since [Oct 2019](https://blog.trello.com/50-million-celebration) butler has been integrated into Trello.

You can find the automation settings on the board -> three dots on right side -> Automation, or through the Automation button if it shows up:

[image: Automation settings]

Then go to rules, and work your way through the settings so it has a new rule that has you "join" the card when it's created.

I just wanted to be added when a due date is set so I get notifications, I setup the following rule: `when a due date is set on a card by anyone, join the card`.