# Show creator on a Trello card

Tags: trello, trello-cards

Is it possible to show the creator of a [Trello](https://trello.com/) card on the card, so, that I don't have to open the card to view who added it?

Or is it possible to automatically add the creator as a member when a card is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither thing is a built-in feature of Trello. In fact, the second question came up before, with the same answer:

- [Default card assignment to self](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37452/default-card-assignment-to-self)
- [Trello - Automatically assign member when date is added](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39078/trello-automatically-assign-member-when-date-is-added)

You may want to submit a feature request to Trello (to have an option to show card creator on front of the card), or look into 3rd party tools such as [Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/trello/) to automate the self-assignment process.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a userscript which adds the creation date and the creator name and account link to the Trello card.
You could install it from my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/almaceleste/userscripts) or from [OpenUserJS.org](https://openuserjs.org/scripts/almaceleste/Trello_card_details)